# CSRF Token for Anti Automation for multiple requests

Tags: csrf

Need some inputs for  the CSRF token  design to prevent anti-automation.

1. When a page loads for an user session, a request is given to the server, which would fetch the CSRF token , returned as part of the Get Response of Page Load.

   The idea is to provide a solution, where no major state is stored on the server-except for one token for each user session per request.

   Everytime a request is made (GET/POST), the existing token is validate and a new token is returned from the server to the client.
   This is stored in the user session.

   On sending the POST request, client validates whether the token value is equal to value in the session and server validates, whether the token received in the request is same as the token stored in the session.
2. When the user performs an action, there can be multiple requests to the server at a point  of time from the client side. Or before the earlier request's response is received, there can be another request send from the client application.

   In this case , would the same CSRF token be send? Or should a pool of tokens be returned from the server for the same?
3. Can this token's also be used for GET requests so as to prevent the attacker to not clog the server with replay attacks with the GET requests?
4. Also, should the CSRF token send in the header or body?
5. Is there any need for it to be encrypted?

Comment: What do you mean by "anti-automation"? Do you want to stop bots from interacting with your site? CSRF tokens does not do that!

Answer (score 0):

Generally CSRF-Token is used only when the state change request is made by user. State change means when user perform some **CURD Operation** on Application.

It’s not required to gives bunch of CSRF-token to every form in multistage form. But generally Programmer gives to every single form. Whether that Form is contain any state change action or not

We generally not recommended to use CSRF-token in get request because of GET request logged at multiple places (Logs, Load-Balancer etc.) so it creates risk for your Application .

**Questions:**

> For Updating operation, there are multiple requests send to different modules on the Server. should the CSRF be same or different?

You  can use the same CSRF-token issue one token for each user-session. If your application is perform critical operation than you can go for one token for each form.

> Before a response is received, the screen is allowing user to initiate one more request? what should the CSRF token be send? The assumption is that, once the CSRF token is validated, then a new token is generated and send in the response.

If your application uses the multiple token for a single form of action, then you need to validated that token in each request and in response new token will be given to the user. But generally we haven't recommended these kind of complex implementation. if it is not that much critical application

> CSRF should be send in header or body? Should It be encrypted?

Always in the body not in cookie. There is no need to do encryption on CSRF-Token. It is nothing but a Secure random generated string for validating that the action is intended by that user or not.

For more details, read the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Appreciate your response for the same.

Comment: Appreciate your response for the same. Just for more clarity for my question, for the following scenarios, what value should the CSRF token have? 1. For Updating operation, there are multiple requests send to different modules on the Server. should the CSRF be same or different? . 2.  Before a response is received, the screen is allowing user to initiate one more request? what should the  CSRF token be send?   The assumption is that, once the CSRF token is validated, then a new token is generated and send in the response. Also, CSRF should be send in header or body? Should It be encrypted?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the same and for your point to point inputs. However, the concern I see here is  , if there is one CSRF token per session and not encrypted,  hacker in middle man attack and use the same token and log a request to the application and forge replay attack. 2.Also, if we should not use the same for Get requests, isn't there a possibility that the attacker can clog the system with multiple get requests and  bring down the system. How do we ensure that  replay attack is prevented for get requests, if not CSRF way?

Comment: Also sir, as I understand, if the token is kept for the whole session, it is not deleted and a new token  is not returned. A new token is send in the response, only when a new session is spawned - for user login etc or refreshing  the browser etc. kindly correct.

Comment: @Jiya Whenever users logins-in the token will assign to that user and remains same until session got expired or logout event is fired.after login again new token is assigned to that user.If answer is usual for you than you can vote for my answer

Comment: Thanks . Kindly let me know for the comment before that, posting that again.  However, the concern I see here is , if there is one CSRF token per session and not encrypted, hacker in middle man attack and use the same token and log a request to the application and forge replay attack. 2.Also, if we should not use the same for Get requests, isn't there a possibility that the attacker can clog the system with multiple get requests and bring down the system. How do we ensure that replay attack is prevented for get requests, if not CSRF way?

Comment: @Jiya,In the case of Web application you can use HTTPS And HSTS Header to prevent against eavesdropping.Always use defense in depth.DO NOT depend on single layer of security !!!

Comment: Thanks again . However, the user  can still copy the same request and cause replay attack on the server. https just takes care of not seeing the request contents, however , does not stop changing it since, the public key of the site is always available. 2. Also for  Get requests, if not CSRF way, what is the other way of anti-automation

Comment: @Jiya,If you want to prevent the replay attack come from user.than you can use timestamp,nonces,OTP etc
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack

Comment: Encrypt the current timestamp using AES, with a key known only to the server, then write the encrypted value to a hidden field in your form.  When the form is submitted, decrypt the value in the hidden field, and check if the decrypted timestamp is between M and N minutes ago (where M is the shortest amount of time that it would reasonably take for a person to complete the form, and N is the longest).  If the decryption fails, or if the timestamp is <M or the timestamp is >N, then you can assume it's an automation attempt.